# Issues with using a for loop with conditional formatting in XlsxWriter

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

Python 2.7:

I am trying to bold all the cells that contain a certain text in excel using XlsxWriter. I have stored the text in a list and used a for loop to iterate over the elements. I am not sure if I am using the correct syntax for specifying the value of the 'value' key in the `conditional_format` dictionary that XlsXwriter offers. The cells that contain the strings in my dictionary are not being converted into bold format.

```
header_format = new_wb.add_format({'bold': True})

header_list = ["Issue", "Type", "Status", "Resolution", "Summary", "Priority", "Fix Version", "Labels"]

for i in range(len(header_list)):
    new_ws.conditional_format('A1:Z999', {'type': 'cell', 'criteria': 'equal to', 'value': '"header_list[i]"' , 'format': header_format})
```

Comment: What is your *question*? What happened when you tried the code? Is that different from what you want? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the header strings as the values in conditional format, and they need to be double quoted (as required by Excel). You are trying to do that but your syntax is wrong. Here is a corrected version based on your example:

```py
import xlsxwriter

new_wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
new_ws = new_wb.add_worksheet()

header_format = new_wb.add_format({'bold': True})

header_list = ["Issue", "Type", "Status", "Resolution",
               "Summary", "Priority", "Fix Version", "Labels"]

for value in header_list:
    new_ws.conditional_format('A1:Z999', {'type': 'cell',
                                          'criteria': 'equal to',
                                          'value': '"%s"' % value,
                                          'format': header_format})

# Write some strings to test against.
new_ws.write_column('A1', ['Foo', 'Type', 'Bar', 'Status'])

new_wb.close()
```

Output with the target words in bold:

[image]